# Getting error while importing a project in android studio which is using realm database

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileFreeDebug'.

> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
>       - realm-android-0.80.0.jar (io.realm:realm-android:0.80.0)
>     Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
>     See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.